# How to fix variable declaration and global constructor warnings?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading *C++ How To Program* and trying to play with what I've learned so far (ha!) and written this program. (It's my own thing, not an exercise from the book.) The output is what I want but I'm unable to fix the warnings.

My use of the `random` stuff in Game.h is based on what I've seen in the book.

If I put the lines causing the warnings inside `main()` the errors go away but the compiler throws a fatal error because it no longer has access to the variable `engine`. I understand that much.

I'm feeling frustrated because I thought I was learning C++ but the C++11 stuff seems to quickly go over my head.

Game.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine engine( static_cast< unsigned int >( time(0) ) );
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > randomInt( 0, 23 );
void initPieces( std::array< int, 24 >& );
void showPieces( std::array< int, 24 > );
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main() {
  std::array< int, 24 > piecesPlayer1 = {};
  std::array< int, 24 > piecesPlayer2 = {};
  initPieces ( piecesPlayer1 );
  initPieces ( piecesPlayer2 );
}

void initPieces( std::array< int, 24 >& myPieces) {
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 24; i += 3 ) {
    myPieces[ i ] = 1;
    myPieces[ i + 1 ] = 2;
    myPieces[ i + 2 ] = 3;
  }
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 24; i++ ) {
    int s = randomInt( engine );
    std::swap ( myPieces[ i ], myPieces[ static_cast<unsigned int>( s ) ] );
  }
  showPieces ( myPieces );
}

void showPieces( std::array< int, 24 > myPieces) {
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 24; i++ ) {
    std::cout << myPieces[ i ] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to include the warnings.

```
rm -fr build/*
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat src/main.cpp -o build/main -Isrc/
In file included from src/main.cpp:1:
src/Game.h:7:28: warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'engine' [-Wmissing-variable-declarations]
std::default_random_engine engine( static_cast< unsigned int >( time(0) ) );
                           ^
src/Game.h:7:28: warning: declaration requires a global constructor [-Wglobal-constructors]
std::default_random_engine engine( static_cast< unsigned int >( time(0) ) );
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/Game.h:8:38: warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'randomInt' [-Wmissing-variable-declarations]
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > randomInt( 0, 23 );
                                     ^
src/Game.h:8:38: warning: declaration requires a global constructor [-Wglobal-constructors]
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > randomInt( 0, 23 );
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
./build/main
2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 3 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2
2 3 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: What is  the warning?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep. I forgot to include them. I have edited them in.

Comment: My *guess*? Because you defined the variables inside the header file. Header files should almost never *define* variable, only *declare* them. Think about what happens if you attempt to include the same header file in multiple source files. Then the variable would be defined in multiple places which isn't allowed. For such a simple program as yours, you don't really need a header file. It's only useful if you need variable or function declarations, or structures, in multiple source files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's good info. Originally I didn't have a header file but it was one of the many things I tried while trying to work this problem on my own.

Comment: Do not use `-Weverything` with clang unless you really, really know what you are doing.

Comment: Use `-Wall` instead of `-Weverything`.  Unless you are OCD like me, then use `-Weverything` and be prepared to do tons of code touch up... because it's fun!

Comment: Are you using c++17?

Comment: @Eljay Okay, I switched to <code>-Wall</code> and it compiles and runs with no warnings. I guess that means those warnings are above Newbie paygrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using C++17, you can decorate game.h with `inline` thusly:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

inline std::default_random_engine engine(static_cast< unsigned int >(time(0)));
inline std::uniform_int_distribution< int > randomInt(0, 23);
void initPieces(std::array< int, 24 >&);
void showPieces(std::array< int, 24 >);
```

For old C++, change the header to this:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

extern std::default_random_engine engine;
extern std::uniform_int_distribution< int > randomInt;
void initPieces(std::array< int, 24 >&);
void showPieces(std::array< int, 24 >);
```

Put the definitions into main.cpp or some other compilation unit, e.g. game.cpp.

```
std::default_random_engine engine(static_cast< unsigned int >(time(0)));
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > randomInt(0, 23);
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I'm using C+11 without total understanding of why because the book I'm learning from uses it. I know nothing of C++17. I did move the definitions out of the header file, though.

Comment: The answer covers C++11 also. Read further.

Comment: In the "old version" the header object declarations must have `extern` -- otherwise they are still definitions, just with no constructor arguments given